# React JS Mui ui Проблемма с передачей значения в Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mobx, mobx-react-lite, mui

```
<Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={labels2}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.marketplaceType}
        value={labels}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => change(event,newValue)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="Маркетплейсы"
            placeholder="Маркетплейс"
          />
        )}
      />
```

Есть autocomplete, хочу записать изменения в mobx стэйт. Чтобы при открытии страницы value было сохранено. Я пытаюсь передать 2 разных массива. Один в option, второй в value. И штука интересная, autocomplete корректно работает если данные в 2 элемента useState (labels,labels2) были переданы из одного массива. Логику сохранения данных в стейт понять чет не могу.
Т.е. У меня получается 2 массива. Первый хранит в себе весь список вариантов, второй отображает value (выбранные). Когда я передаю данные из двух разных источников, пускай и с одинаковыми объектами, все работает криво (не происходит сопоставление выбранных элементов со списком).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Понятно. Посмотрел внимательно api mui, нужно юзать isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.marketplaceType === value.marketplaceType}